# Azure AD exception - AADSTS50105 - “The signed in user is not assigned to a role for the application”. Is it possible to modify this message?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

Is it possible to modify these kinds of error messages on a per-application basis?  It would be really nice to tell the user whom to contact to be granted a role rather than to just ring the help desk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible to modify this error message. The product team has been working to add this in the near future. Many have posted this feedback in the AAD feedback forum and you can upvote it and subscribe for updates from the product team. https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/32128597-allow-for-customized-error-messages-in-azure-ad-co

Comment: @marilee-turscak-msft   Thank you for following up.